# Why does a socket server allow connections on multiple ports but only allow a single connection per port

Tags: sockets

There is a socket server that our application needs to connect to and it has this rather odd design that it offers multiple ports to connect on, but only a single socket client can connect on each one.  If a subsequent socket server attempts to connect on a 'used' listening socket, it gets rejected.

Is there a reason for designing a socket server in this way?  My question is why?

Comment: What do people who built the server say?

Comment: Maybe they just didn't know how do do it properly.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is it's using a UDP socket and only allowing one binding per port as opposed to a TCP socket where the server listens on one port and accepted connections are handled by other non-listening sockets.